# A customized object array sort in Java that does not sort

Tags: java, android, sorting

I've read a few tutorials on customizing Arrays.sort, and a lot of googling, but I'm missing the answer. Right now Arrays.sort(charList) does nothing. Here's what my code looks like.

```
public class character implements Comparable<character>{

//public vars
public String charName;
public int initModifier;
public int initRoll;
public int secondInit;
/* ... getters, setters, other vars .. */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(character another) {
        int compareInit = ((character) another).getTotalInit();
        int comp = this.totalInit - compareInit;
        int compareSecondInit = ((character) another).getTotalInit();

        if (comp != 0)
        {
            return comp;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.secondInit - compareSecondInit;
        }
    }
}
```

The main activity is a bundle of stuff. The part that deals with the arrays.sort follows:

```
//add a character to the array.
public void addResults(character c)
{
    debugInt++; //using this to debug
    if(debugInt==3)
    {
        Log.d(tag,charList[0].charName); //always prints the first object entered
        Log.d(tag,charList[1].charName); //always prints the second object entered
    }
    if (playersPerTurn<charLimit)
    {
        charList[playersPerTurn]=c;
        Arrays.sort(charList,0,playersPerTurn); 
        playersPerTurn++;
        updateDisplay();
    }
}
```

Help me SO, you're my only hope.

Comment: Have you tried testing `compareTo()` by creating a few `character`s and printing out the result of comparing them?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The data I was loading wouldn't have given me an answer there, but I wasn't considering this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int compareSecondInit = ((character) another).getTotalInit();
```

You probably wanted `getSecondInit()` here. 

Your `compareTo()` with this bug  is not consistent - and thus the result is undefined.

**for example:**

```
element1:
totalInit = 1
secondInit = 2
element2:
totalInit = 1
secondInit = 2

element1.compareTo(element2) == 2 - 1 == 1
element2.compareTo(element1) == 2 - 1 == 1
```

As a side note, about coding practice:

1. Naming a class `character` is confusing, you should consider renaming it.
2. In java, the convention is that class names start with upper case letters. It will help fellow programmers to easily understand `character` is a class and not a field.

Comment: I cant believe I spent ~three hours not seeing that. Thanks amit.